# Pooling 2 internet connections

Tags: home-networking, dd-wrt

I am looking for ways to pool 2 or more  connections.  The "basic need" is to use the best connection if one is slow, or not really reaching the Internet, but more sophisticated combinations are of course useful.

I am thinking of:

1. PC (Windows, perhaps Mac, Linux) with  LAN and Wi-FI (Easiest, I presume)
2. Router (dd-wrt) - Would like to pool the Internet gateway (WAN) and a LAN client with Wi-FI (What I need most)
3. Android Devices
4. Wi-Fi cards poling different hotspots.

More advanced use would be utilizing both connections.  For example one to the max, the other as needed.  Or limited use of an expensive connection (To make sure there is some connectivity)

The "basic need" is of course meet (But not very good), for (3), with the Wi-FI/Mobile data connection and also for (4).

Primarily without buying a new router, but could buy some cheap hardware.

Comment: There are routers with 2 WAN ports. The question is, how many actual internet connections do you have? Are you talking about wifi from neighbours that you have access too?

Comment: At home Cable provider WAN and commercial Wi-Fi providers (requiring a logon) 
When travelling, Wi-FI and Mobile Data,  sometimes several Mobile Data providers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements completely. But Android 5.0 has the Smart Network Switch feature under Settings->Wifi which seems to do what you want. It switches to the best or more stable network it can find that you've configured. It will try different bands (5.8/2.4). It verifies that the connection is actually working. And if that network goes down, it keeps trying and will eventually fail to the cellular data network. Wifi is prefered over cellular, so it will keep an eye out for new wifi opportunities. You are still required to login to APs that require web based authentication, but it will popup in a browser automatically for you most of the time.

Otherwise to do this on some other OS, I fear you may have to write some code to behave like android does. Unless someone else already has. If someone has please let me know, it would be nice.

Comment: (As I tried to explain) I think/know Wi-Fi clients can switch between access points, but in my experience it doesn't work to well, esp. with strong signal, but no/weak Internet connection (Like when you need a sign-on).
I think its much the same between Mobile Data and Wi-Fi.

It is possible newer android versions does it better, but in my case I often need sign-in, So I would probably need to find an app for that.